# Syncing React-Slick with Query Params

Tags: react-slick

I'm using React-Slick to render `<Report />` components in a carousel. I would like to sync each `<Report />`'s `reportId` with query params.

For example, a user would be able to see a specific report by going to `myapp.com/reports?id=1` and it would take them to that specific "slide".

The problem I'm having is that the `report` data is being loaded before the slides are initialized. I can't find any good examples of react-slick's `onInit` or `onReInit`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `onInit` or `onReInit`, I just utilized the `initialSlide` setting and used `componentDidUpdate()`.

```
componentDidUpdate = (prevProps, prevState) => {

const queryParams = qs.parse(this.props.location.search)
if (prevProps.reports !== this.props.reports) {
  const sortedReports = this.sortReportsByDate(this.props.reports)

  this.setSlideIndex(sortedReports.findIndex(i => i.id === parseInt(queryParams.reportId, 10)))
  this.setQueryParams({
    reportId: this.sortReportsByDate(this.props.reports)[this.state.slideIndex].id
  })
}

if (prevState.slideIndex !== this.state.slideIndex) {
  this.setQueryParams({
    reportId: this.sortReportsByDate(this.props.reports)[this.state.slideIndex].id
  })
}

}
```

And the settings:

```
const settings = {
  ...
  initialSlide: reportsSortedByDate.findIndex(i => i.id === parseInt(queryParams.reportId, 10))
  ...
}
```

I hope someone finds this useful!