# Indexing specific slides using React-slick w/ URL Routing

Tags: react-slick

I am trying to use React-slide to load a series of dynamically-driven card components. The number of cards will change frequently by platform users. I have so far been successful in passing prop data, mapped onto React-slick slides. Navigation works.

Context for next steps:
Users should be able to create slides and sliders, which can be related but decoupled. A slide can get moved or shared onto other sliders for example.

I want to be able to index the slides in such a way where each slide can be accessed by entering a unique URL param (likely the ID from the slide prop data) - eg. platform.com/slider/[:sliderID]?s=[:slideID]. IF and WHEN the number of slides changes by users, I want the URL to map to the proper React-slick slide. I could either use the goToSlide approach or update the initialSlide setting as in the example below (which seems better to me).

[Syncing React-Slick with Query Params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54656337/syncing-react-slick-with-query-params)
posted by Joe. Would love to connect Joe!

Unfortunately, I'm struggling with translating the class component solution (from Joe's example) into a functional component syntax. Any help would be greatly appreciated.